# Compile R package with `-static` flag

Tags: r, compilation, package, rcpp

Is it possible to compile R packages (with or without Rcpp and BH) statically linked (like we compile C/C++ programs with `-static` flag)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not really:

- all R packages are *dynamically loaded* by `dyn.load()` (or the equivalent via `NAMESPACE` etc -- `dyn.load()` is what you do with an individual shared library)
- the dynamically-loaded code is then called via, say, `.Call()`

That cannot work statically.